# Edit The List Text Box of A form From Another Form

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, edit

I am triying to Add item in a listtexbox 1 in A form1 from Another form. But it didn't work.
In the form1 the method :

```
`Public Sub SetListe(ByRef message As String)
    Me.LTB_User.Items.Add(message)

End Sub`
```

In the form2

```
form1.show()

Form1.SetListe("test")
```

doesn't add test in the form1 listtextbox

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the form1.show() after the Form1.SetListe("test"). I think your List box is getting shown before it is being set so you will never see the part being added

Comment: Yes but the problem is that i want to add data to the listtextbox of the form1 when the form1 is show and visible. and i want to add data from another form.